# "How were the Holidays?"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Is it correct to say:

> Wie geht's Dir die Ferien?

Not sure if it makes sense or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say:

> Wie waren deine Ferien?

Or

> Wie war dein Urlaub?

Answer (score 4):

Baz answer `Wie waren deine Ferien??` or `Wie war dein Urlaub?` is correct. It's the question `How are your Holidays` - you are asking a specific person about his/her holiday.

You may also say `Wie waren die Ferien?`or `Wie war der Urlaub?`. This is a more general question. It could be asked to a group (e.g. a teacher could ask a class and everybody could tell about his/her holiday).

`Wie geht's Dir die Ferien?` is wrong. `Wie geht es Dir in den Ferien?` would be something like `How do you feel during your holidays` - it's no about the past and it sound a bit strange.